# How to view order by dec in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to view data order by dec by class_id. But it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
$posts=Status::where('class_id',$id)->get();
```

Now what is the right formet to solved it?

Comment: $posts = Status::where('class_id' , $id)->orderBy('class_id', 'desc')->get();

Comment: It's not working desc. Brother.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its solved. Its should be $posts = Status::where('class_id' , $id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

Comment: You have mentioned class_id that is why  i used  the same , i thought class_id is your primary key .